# Why can't I open Genymotion virtual device I newly installed?

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion

I newly installed virtual device in genymotion. But when I try to run it, it can not start. I got the error message below:

"Unable to start the virtual device.
VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device.
Your CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies"

here is the error image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ0aN.jpg

My genymotion is installed in xUbuntu20.04, xUbuntu20.04 is installed in virtualbox, and virtualbox is installed in Win10.
My CPU has enable Virtualization Technology, and virtualbox has enable VT-x/AMD-V.

Can anyone suggest how can I resolve this problem.

My Device Info: ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 AMD Ryzen5 4500U

Answer (score 0):

What is your CPU? If it's AMD, you need to enable SVM in the BIOS as well as AMD-V.

Comment: Of course I have enabled AMD-V in BIOS, that's why my virtualbox can run Ubuntu.

Comment: So you are running Genymotion from an Ubuntu VM? In that case, it is not going to work, no matter what. Genymotion needs to be run from a real host, not a virtual environment (See https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/3.1/01_Get_started/011_Requirements.html#operating-systems)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that can explain why my genymotion can't run in Ubuntu VM.